# Blur event not triggered on VTextField

Tags: vuejs2, event-handling, vuetify.js, blur, onblur

I've created a date/time picker component that is using two VTextField's to enter hour and minute values. There're three events on each field. Two of the events, *focus* and *input* do call their respective handlers when triggered. But the *blur* event does not.

The code for the VTextField is like this:

```
        <v-text-field
          v-model="minutes"
          class="time-box"
          placeholder="--"
          @blur="setHoursOrMinutes($event)"
          @focus="clearValue($event.target)"
          @input="checkValue($event)"
        />
```

Thank you!

Comment: You'll need to provide enough code to reproduce the issue.  A single `<v-text-field>` by itself has no issues with it's `blur` event listener ([codepen example](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/dyqOBJJ) where it console logs on focus, blur, and input).  If you can provide a reproducible example in a codepen or other sandbox, or even by providing more code snippets, that would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Check whether $('blur') event is triggered inside the component, if not, trigger the event inside the component

```
<input @blur="$emit('blur',your value)"></input>
```